# Android HTML5 playback

Tags: android, html, webviewchromium

Can someone explain me how works html video playback on Android OS? I'm interested in low level.. Which player invokes html stremaing? Is that part of chromium project? How to gain access to that player?

Or at least point me to some useful resources...